# Exercise 1-21, C Programming Language, Final Line Explanation

Tags: c, tabs

Exercise 1-21 C Programming Language Kernighan

Please explain the final line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABINC 8

/* replace strings of blanks with tabs and blanks */
int main()
{
    int c, nb, nt, pos;

    nb = 0;   /* number of blanks necessary */
    nt = 0;   /* number of tabs necessary   */
    for (pos = 1; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++pos)
       if (c == ' ') {
           if (pos % TABINC != 0)
                 ++nb;                /* increment # of blanks */
           else {
                 nb = 0;              /* reset # of blanks */
                 ++nt;                /* one more tab      */
            }
          } else {
                 for ( ; nt > 0 ; --nt)
                        putchar('\t')        /* output tab(s)   */
                 if (c == '\t')              /* forget the blank(s) */
                       nb = 0;
                 else
                    for ( ; nb > 0; --nb)
                         putchar(' ');
                 putchar(c);
                 if (c == '\n')
                    pos = 0;
                 **else if (c == '\t')
                    pos = pos + (TABINC - (pos-1) % TABINC) - 1;
          }
}**
```

I am having difficulties interpreting the final line . . . can you please explain how to decipher the arithmetic?

What does this mean?
             else if (c == '\t')
                    pos = pos + (TABINC - (pos-1) % TABINC) - 1;

Comment: You understand `if (c == '\n')` but don't understand what `else if (c == '\t')` does? They're practically identical except for the character being compared with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (c == '\t')
```

tests if the current character is a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character.

```
pos = pos + (TABINC - (pos-1) % TABINC) - 1;
```

calculates the next multiple of `TABINC` columns from the current `pos` column.

`(pos-1) % TABINC` is the number of characters between the last tab stop and the current position; e.g. if `pos == 10`, `pos-1` is `9`, and `9 % 8` is `1`. The next tab stop is `16`, which is `10 + (8 - 1) - 1`.